# O Pi 3 LTS Android can't access GPIO

Tags: orange-pi

I tried to access and modify GPIO through the file system, but I can't find the /sys/class/gpio directory.

I installed Debian and was able to change GPIO this way, but I need to do it with Android.

I can't find the /sys/class/gpio directory.

Comment: There is a tutorial on using GPIO with Android on the Orange Pi [forum](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepibbsen/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=6973&mobile=2)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I am also using the android to control the GPIO of Orange Pi.
What have to be done:
Configure the GPIO of Orange Pi first in Linux distribution
this will enable the directory '/sys/class/gpio/export' in android